# Typescript with Lodash, Why allow to input wrong key name to function?

Tags: typescript, lodash

I used typescript with lodash, for example `_.OrderBY`. I found TS allow us to put wrong key to lodash's function.

```
import _ from "lodash";

interface Data {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const dataLists = [
  { name: "A", age: 18 },
  { name: "B", age: 50 },
  { name: "C", age: 45 }
];

const order = _.orderBy<Data>(dataLists, "age2222");
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-poincare-xhdryd?file=/src/index.ts

## **I think for TS should not allow us to put the wrong key name and display error on `age2222`, how can we do that?**

I have investigated about type in Lodash until I found that second parameter type came from this.

```
type IterateeShorthand<T> = PropertyName | [PropertyName, any] | PartialShallow<T>;
type PropertyName = string | number | symbol;
```

`PropertyName` allow all `string`, I think this the root cause that not display error but I don't understand, why?

Please correct me if i'm misunderstand.